Bond Option Convexity
As part of my learning, I came across bond convexity and was wondering how that would apply to bond options, as in would it be the expectation of ytm ? How do we define it? Are there any good articles/ book chapters in can read that would explain it?
Thank you so much!!

Personally, I like "Bond Markets: Structures and Yield Calculations (1998)". Section 4.8 on convexity.

A bit more depth from my comment:

Bond convexity is to do with the non linear relationship between price and yield. Namely, as yields fall the price of the bond (assuming its non callable and no other embedded optionality in it) will increase more than it would fall for a similar change in yield.

Bond option convexity, also known as gamma is to do with the fact that the payoff of an option is nonlinear. That is, if you are hovering around the strike the change in your sensitivity ('delta') to the underlying can change substantially. For example if you are a few mins before expiry and your option is OTM, your delta would be very small. Now if the market rallies a few ticks taking you through the strike your delta goes to 100%. This rapid change in delta is gamma at work.


Both are due to convex relationships between variables, however, its due to different variables.
